# QTP vs Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, qtp

I have largely worked with Selenium for front end automation. Looks like there is great market for QTP in this arena, especially when you could afford commercial tools.

> Have you worked with both QTP and Selenium? How have your experiences been with both? Do you find any one better over other?

Comment: This won't end well, is VERY argumentative and should be closed. I know because I have the arguments all the time ... jump over to meta, we have already pre-empted this question

Comment: Agreed. I can think of pros of both, but... this is just begging a holy war. Consider if you went to SO and said "C++ or Java? Which is better?" how fast it'd be closed.

Comment: agreed, voted for closing

Comment: I'm not sure it should be closed; monitored sure, but not closed. It is an important question of tools that really do compete in the area of automated web testing.

Comment: I strongly disagree that questions like this should be closed.  I would MUCH rather see thoughtful analyses of the pro's and cons of tools (and other potentially decisive issues) aired and decide for myself which perspectives I find more compelling than have moderators conclude that participants are too immature to discuss the issues politely and rationally.  If participants can't be trusted to discuss topics like this politely and rationally, the community has bigger issues to worry about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have worked on both, and used QTP extensively before.  It works best for teams that have one or two engineers who can create and maintain the test suites, and few more QAs with not so much programming skills can run the tests, and make minor changes.  It's record and play (IMO) is better than selenium's.

Selenium is open source, so you are saving a lot of money that you would have to pay for licenses.   Technologically Selenium surely goes way beyond QTP can, and due to the support for programming languages like JAVA, C#, Perl, Python, etc. the QA engineers can encompass backend tests too in their test suites.

Comment: +1 for approach this with a balanced approach, noting the benefits of each and avoiding religious arguments. In other words, way to be insightful without being inciteful. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, selenium is better for web testing.

QTP is more expensive, and uses old technologies (VBA), but is better for non-coders and testing desktop applications

**Now please, please, please close this question before the inevitable argument comes.**

Comment: @Downvoter, I'm curious why you downvoted this answer. I think it's a reasoned, legitimate response.

Comment: Is any answer downvoted? though I myself marked it for close

Comment: yes there are ups and down's evening out to zero ... but I expected some when I wrote it :-)