# QA Automation Tool. QTP vs Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, qtp

My department is currently looking at a tool for QA automation. On that side we are looking at both QTP and Selenium.

The major features we want are automation of regression testing, something easily implemented, something with a scheduler and the ability to match test cases to requirements.

We only build web based applications in our department. Currently all testing is done manually just prior to the deployment of new applications, bug fixes, and new features, causing an extreme burden on our QA team.

What are the pros/cons of both?
Level of effort to implement?
Does QTP or Selenium integrate with TFS and/or QC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some links related to your question:

[QTP vs Selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/245/qtp-vs-selenium?rq=1)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774255/qtp-vs-selenium-compare

http://blog.testing-whiz.com/2013/06/comparing-qtp-selenium-and-testingwhiz.html