# What is the major difference between selenium and QTP

Tags: selenium, qtp

I am yet to start my career. Have completed by BCA and want to move it software testing segment. Please suggest which one to learn Selenium or QTP.

Comment: Voting to close this question; as this is exact duplicate of these questions: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/245/qtp-vs-selenium    and  https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7723/qa-automation-tool-qtp-vs-selenium

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to go for Selenium.

Selenium is an open source tool and requires a lot of coding in order to perform automation testing. For example, you have to write functions for file operations (in order to read and write from the files). Whereas QTP being a paid tool, has many inbuilt functionalities like file operations, capturing screens and many more.

So, as a learner, it is always good to start with a tool with least support.

That way, in future if you get to work on a tool which is more automation friendly (in terms of built-in functionality and support) then you will find it easier to work with such tool. But, if you start with a tool that is more automation friendly then you will end up with limited hands on experience on different aspects associated with automation framework and development.

For detailed differences between Selenium and QTP. Refer to the below link:

http://www.aspiresys.com/WhitePapers/QTPvsSelenium.pdf

Let me know if you any further further questions